# Difference in the output of WriteLine vs Write

Tags: c#

Coming from a background of C/C++, I wasn't expecting to see any difference in the output of using

```
file.WriteLine("FINISH");
```

vs using

```
file.Write("FINISH\n");
```

The output of the first line matches the output of

```
file.WriteLine("FINISH\r\n");
```

Is that expected?

Here's a complete program for testing.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace StreamTest
{
   class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         var file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("D:/temp/test.out", false);
         file.WriteLine("FINISH");
         file.Write("FINISH\n");
         file.Write("FINISH\r\n");
         file.Close();
      }
   }
}
```

The difference in output is visible when I use gvim. Here's an image from seeing the file in gvim.

[image]

Comment: Why wouldn't you expect a difference? If you're on Windows, then `\n` is not enough to introduce a new line.

Comment: Welcome to the world of C# where everything is done for you and there is a shortcut if you need it

Comment: If you have a situation where you want to manually insert newlines, `Environment.NewLine` is probably a better option than specifying your escape characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdf6yhx5(v=vs.110).aspx) says:

> You can change the line terminator by setting the TextWriter.NewLine property of the Out property to another string. The example provides an illustration.

Looking at the github source for [TextWriter](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/io/textwriter.cs), it can be seen

```
public virtual String NewLine {
    get { return new String(CoreNewLine); }
```

where CoreNewLine is

```
protected char[] CoreNewLine = new char[] { '\r', '\n' };
```

Considering .Net  started first in Windows, where new line is \r\n, it is not surprising.

It would be interesting to look at the Mono implementation.

Comment: GitHub source? Why not `referencesource.microsoft.com`?

Answer (score 2):

```
\n = LF (Line Feed) // Used as a new line character in Unix
\r = CR (Carriage Return) // Used as a new line character in Mac OS
\n\r = CR + LF // Used as a new line character in Windows
```

`Console.WriteLine` uses `\r\n` while in `Write` you are only using `\n`.

Also, take this into account that if you plan to use this cross-platform:

> The default line terminator is a string whose value is a carriage
>   return followed by a line feed ("\r\n" in C#, or vbCrLf in Visual
>   Basic). You can change the line terminator by setting the
>   TextWriter.NewLine property of the Out property to another string.

So, this would be:

```
System.Console.Out.NewLine = "\r";
```

Comment: FWIW, the information you quoted is incorrect. `\n` is line feed LF). `\r` is carriage return (CR). See http://www.asciitable.com/.

Comment: @RSahu fixed, see edit

Comment: I am glad that you fixed your answer but unfortunately, the original post you quoted remains wrong. Oh well. We can't change that from here.